# json.dumps() not saving content to file

Tags: python, json

I am using python 2.7 on mac. The following code creates a file 'test.json' with no content in it.

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as fout: json.dumps({'name': u'lala'}, fout)
```

When using `json.dump()`, the file does have content. Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) serializes object to a string instead of file:

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str using this conversion table. If ensure_ascii is False, the result may contain non-ASCII characters and the return value may be a unicode instance.

Example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'name': u'lala'})
'{"name": "lala"}'
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, when the OP passes in the file argument, it will be used as the value of `skipkeys`.